# Swift. iOS. Picture stored in the sandbox disappeared when I run the application again

Tags: ios, swift

```
//the Path of images 
public let appMainDirectory = NSHomeDirectory()+"/Documents"

public let imgDirectory = appMainDirectory+"/images"


//the UIImage comes from a UIImageView
func saveImageToLocal(_ img:UIImage)->String{
        //get image's data
        let imgData:Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0)!
        //use time as file name
        let time:Date = Date()
        let timeFormat = DateFormatter()
        timeFormat.dateFormat = "yyyMMddHHmmssSSS"
        let imgName = timeFormat.string(from: time) as String
        let imgURL:String = imgDirectory+"/"+imgName+".jpg"
        //store image into sandbox
        writeDataToEndOfFile(fileURL: imgURL, contentToWrite:imgData, create: true)

        return imgURL
}


func writeDataToEndOfFile(fileURL url1:String,contentToWrite fileData:Data,create createOrNot:Bool){

    let fM:FileManager = FileManager.default

    if( !fM.fileExists(atPath:url1)  &&  createOrNot ){
        fM.createFile(atPath: url1, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
    }
    let fUpdater:FileHandle = FileHandle(forUpdatingAtPath: url1)!
    fUpdater.seekToEndOfFile()
    fUpdater.write(fileData)
    fUpdater.closeFile()
}


func readImage(imageUrl url:String) -> UIImage? {

    let fM:FileManager = FileManager.default

    if( !fM.fileExists(atPath:url)){
        print(fM.fileExists(atPath:url))
        fM.createFile(atPath: url, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        print(fM.fileExists(atPath:url))
    }
    let fUpdater:FileHandle = FileHandle(forUpdatingAtPath: url)!
    let imageData:Data = fUpdater.availableData
    fUpdater.closeFile()
    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)

    return image
}
```

In every launch, images stored in previous launches seemed to disappear. If I try to use the 'readImage' function, the app will crash and the error is 'unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional value'.

By the way, the outputs of two 'print(fM.fileExists(atPath:url))' are both false.

Comment: Your code for building a path to the Documents folder is all wrong. There are countless examples showing the proper way.

Comment: @rmaddy so how to build?

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention that I created the image folder: try! FM1.createDirectory(atPath: imgDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)

Comment: I tried using: "let docDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray; public let appMainDirectory = docDirs[0] as! String " to create the path to Documents folder, but it didn't work out

Comment: @rmaddy Still I haven't found a solution. All the images can be read and displayed until I update the application, but they disappear after. And when I updated the app a txt file I created still exist with all of its content inside. I will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve this.

The problem is not in the codes above. These codes works well.
The reason I cannot find my image anymore is because the app's sandbox's URL will change in every update. And because I was still trying to use the URL from previous version to read the image, the error occurs.